# How to encrypt/decrypt text in IBM Image services

Tags: filenet, filenet-image-services

Could you please help me here, we are using OLD version of IBM Filenet Image Services 4.2 version. We are seeing encrypted password in a file called "repository.properties". We want to decrypt this text to see it's value.

Will be grateful to you if you could help me in same.

Answer (score 3):

IBM FileNet Image Services uses a single-key internal proprietary encryption algorithm for encrypting user passwords. The encryption algorithm adds random bits to the password depending on the time of the day thus even when tracing the network traffic, the same password will appear different on every network transfer.

The server decrypts the password then encrypts it again to compare the final encrypted password with the encrypted password that exists in the MKF security database. The password in the MKF database is stored as encrypted data. On IS 4.1.2 and IS 4.2 the internal encryption algorithm used is a 256 bit encryption. On IS 4.1.1 it uses a 16 bit encryption.

Based on the above it is nearly impossible to decrypt the password. rater, your best bet would be to blank it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't decrypt this password. You can blank it, then re-setup the connection to the Image Services repository in IBM Content Navigator.